# ACAccount Facebook property username return email and sometimes the nickname

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7, acaccount, acaccountstore

When I access to the Facebook Account using `ACAccountStore` to get an `ACAccount` object I noticed that for some profiles the `ACAccount.username` give me the Facebook email but for other profiles give me the nickname... How is possible that the same property contains different value ?

This drive me crazy...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's weird for me too. 
But I can get the email from properties field like below:

```
NSString *email = [[account valueForKey:@"properties"] objectForKey:@"ACUIDisplayUsername"];
```